# Prevent fixed element from disappearing when on page with relative positioned element

Tags: css, css-position

I must completely misunderstand `position: fixed;`.

I would like the fixed element at the bottom of the page to always occupy the bottom of the screen.  It works as expected on Chrome 48.0.2564.116 Mac 10.9.5, even when the window is resized such that `window.document.body.clientWidth` is less than the left position of the relative element, i.e. 400px, which is less than 510px .  But viewing this page in Chrome on Android results in the `.justifiedBottom` component disappearing off the bottom of the screen if the relative positioned element is positioned at with a left value greater than the width of the screen (or if its width is not set to 0px (?!)).

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <style>
    .positionedRelative {
      position:relative;
      top: 300px;
      width: 0px;
      left: 510px;
    }

    .justifiedBottom {
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.5);
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="positionedRelative">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="justifiedBottom">Next Page</div>
</body>
</html>
```

With a clientWidth of 360 and left position of .positionedRelative of 322px, the following is produced (note that the fixed element is being pushed off the bottom of the screen):

[image: fixed element is being pushed off the bottom of the screen]

Any thoughts or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I think this is related to meta tag and this article and related should be useful but haven't got my head round yet:  http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, it's to do with your widths. Take a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lqnfmad/3/

```
.positionedAbsolute { position:absolute; top: 300px; width: 100%; left: 0px; text-align: center; }
.justifiedBottom { padding: 15px; background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.5); position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; }
```

See if that helps you!

Comment: Apologies I incorrectly said `absolute` positioned, when in fact it's a `relative` positioned element.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter.  Both absolute and relative elements positioned off to the right of the screen cause the fixed element to disappear and your current css actually makes it worse... change the `.positionedAbsolute` left to 30px and it already pushed the fixed element off the screen (on chrome, on android, on a phone with screen width 360 px).

Answer (score 0):

** Edit ** This **does not work**.  If you change `.positionedRelative` left value to something a bit bigger, e.g. 420 the fixed element disappears again (?!!!).

I still don't understand how and why `position: relative;` and `position: fixed;` interfere with each other but **a** solution seems to be to wrap the relative component in an absolute positioned component:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <style>
    .positionedAbsolute {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0; /* Doesn't appear to be required but putting it in for good measure.  */
    }

    .positionedRelative {
      position: relative;
      top: 300px;
      left: 320px;
    }

    .justifiedBottom {
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.5);
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="positionedAbsolute">
    <div class="positionedRelative">
      Hello
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="justifiedBottom">Next Page</div>
</body>
</html>
```